# how to ffill and and letter in pandas?

Tags: pandas

New to the pandas.

Struggling find a way to ffill and concat a string.
I imported excel sheet then like to fill the blank (NaN) with proceeding value plus some distinguisher(like-1).

-from-

```
1 a

2 nan

3 b

4 nan
```

-to-

```
1 a

2 a-1

3 b

4 b-1
```

[excel example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK2JJ.png)
I used `df.fillna(method='ffill')`
But can't figure out how to append '-1' after 'a' and 'b' using 'ffill'.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you do `ffill`, you can compute the order of each rows with `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].ffill()
orders = df.groupby('col').cumcount()

# concatenate the order except for the first rows
df['col'] = np.where(orders==0, df['col'], df['col'] + '-' + orders.astype(str))
```

Comment: why I get 'name 'orders' is not defined '??

Comment: `orders` is defined as `orders = df.groupby('col').cumcount()` right before the last row?